# throwing error executing jar file after executing dos2unix command in linux

Tags: java, linux, dos2unix

I have a jar file which is copied from a windows machine onto unix machine....usually we convert all the files that were copied from windows using dos2unix command..
When I convert the jar file to unix format using dos2unix...I am getting the below error...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error opening job jar: hadoop-examples-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.3.0.jar
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:135)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid END header (bad central directory offset)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:127)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:135)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:133)
```

It ran successfully before running dos2unix command on it...
Any idea why this happened ?

Comment: the conversion just turn 0d0a in 0a... and so you had a zipped file that had that sequence, and you corrupted it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't do that. A `jar` file is the same as a `zip`, it's a binary. `dos2unix` is for converting line endings in ASCII files (not binary).

Comment: I have another jar file I ran dos2unix on it and it working...
Why this is happening for some jar's..not all jars
Some jar files are working after dos2unix and some are not...Why is that ?

Comment: The problem for us is like we have an automated script which convert all the files into dos2unix format.....After conversion some jar files are running fine and some are not....We are trying to figure out the problem

Comment: Because the byte sequence `0D 0A` is not present in all binary files. `0D 0A` (aka '\r\n'), is a carriage-return character followed by a new-line character. dos2unix replaces that sequence with `0A` - or just new-line, because dos and unix use different line ending conventions.

Comment: Run `file` on the files. If it's a binary, don't do that.

Comment: When I do file on a jar files some files giving me the following
Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract
and some are
Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
what that mean ? It doesn't really say binary or ASCII....

Comment: $ file something.jar 
----Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract

$ file somethingelse.jar
----Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract

---What does it mean ? It doesn't really say binary or ASCII....
Sorry previous comment was not properly formatted...

Comment: `$ if [ "$(file ${THE_FILE}  | grep ASCII | wc -l)" == "1" ]; then dos2unix "${THE_FILE}"; fi`